# How do I connect two different stores to the same action in Redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a user store that handles all the user actions, which include fetching user data and updating user information. I've also got a post store that fetches posts users have written and also, posts, updates, and deletes them.

When I update my user information and call my function:

```
export const putUserDataPending = () => {
  return {
    type: "PUT_USER_DATA_PENDING"
  }
}

export const putUserDataFulfilled = user => {
  return {
    type: "PUT_USER_DATA_FULFILLED",
    user: user
  }
}

export const putUserDataRejected = error => {
  return {
    type: "PUT_USER_DATA_REJECTED",
    error: error
  }
}

export const putUserData = (username, email, countries, home) => {
  const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(putUserDataPending());
    axios.put(
      'http://localhost:8000/api/v1/rest-auth/user/',
      {
        username: username,
        email: email,
        countries: countries,
        home: home
      },
      {headers: { 'Authorization': `Token ${token}`}}
  )
      .then(response => {
        const user = response.data;
        dispatch(putUserDataFulfilled(user));
      })
      .catch(err => {
        dispatch(putUserDataRejected(err));
      })
  }
}
```

It rerenders the user profile page, but it doesn't rerender the author information because the state for the posts was never updated. What's the proper way to update any of the author objects in the posts state that may have been updated by updating the user?

Or is it just better to manually rerender the homepage?

My home page MapState is this:

```
const mapState = state => {
  return {
    fetched: state.tripReport.fetched,
    fetching: state.tripReport.fetching,
    tripReports: state.tripReport.tripReports,
    showCountryModal: state.modal.showCountryModal,
    modalCountry: state.modal.modalCountry
  };
}
```

where tripReports is an array of objects, and some of the authors I want to update.

My editProfile MapState looks like this:

```
const mapState = state => {
  return {
    user: state.user.user,
    userCountries: state.user.user.countries,
    searchedCountry: state.country.country,
    showProfileModal: state.modal.showProfileModal,
    modalProfile: state.modal.modalProfile
  };
}
```

Where the user object is the object getting updated.

Here is the post reducer:

```
const initialState = {
  fetching: false,
  fetched: false,
  fetchingTripReports: false,
  fetchedTripReports: false,
  tripReports: [],
  userTripReports: [],
  error: null,
}

export default function (state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "FETCH_TRIP_REPORTS_PENDING": {
      return {
        ...state,
        fetching: true
      }
    }
    case "FETCH_TRIP_REPORTS_FULFILLED": {
      return {
        ...state,
        fetching: false,
        fetched: true,
        tripReports: action.tripReports
      }
    }
    case "FETCH_TRIP_REPORTS_REJECTED": {
      return {
        ...state,
        fetching: false,
        fetched: false,
        error: action.error
      }
    }
    case "FETCH_USER_TRIP_REPORTS_PENDING": {
      return {
        ...state,
        fetchingTripReports: true
      }
    }
    case "FETCH_USER_TRIP_REPORTS_FULFILLED": {
      return {
        ...state,
        fetchingTripReports: false,
        fetchedTripReports: true,
        userTripReports: action.tripReports
      }
    }
    case "FETCH_USER_TRIP_REPORTS_REJECTED": {
      return {
        ...state,
        fetchingTripReports: false,
        fetchedTripReports: false,
        error: action.error
      }
    }
    case "POST_TRIP_REPORTS_PENDING": {
      return {
        ...state,
      }
    }
    case "POST_TRIP_REPORTS_FULFILLED": {
      return {
        ...state,
        // The new trip report must be added onto the array, then the array must be sorted by id.
        userTripReports: [...state.userTripReports].concat(action.response).sort((a, b) => a.id < b.id),
        tripReports: [...state.tripReports].concat(action.response).sort((a, b) => a.id < b.id)
      }
    }
    case "POST_TRIP_REPORTS_REJECTED": {
      return {
        ...state,
        error: action.error
        }
    }
    case "DELETE_TRIP_REPORTS_PENDING": {
      return {
        ...state,
      }
    }
    case "DELETE_TRIP_REPORTS_FULFILLED": {
      return {
        ...state,
        // The deleted post must be filtered out of the lists.
        userTripReports: state.userTripReports.filter(tripReport => tripReport.id !== action.response.id),
        tripReports: state.tripReports.filter(tripReport => tripReport.id !== action.response.id)
      }
    }
    case "DELETE_TRIP_REPORTS_REJECTED": {
      return {
        ...state,
        error: action.error
      }
    }
    case "UPDATE_TRIP_REPORTS_PENDING": {
      return {
        ...state,
      }
    }
    case "UPDATE_TRIP_REPORTS_FULFILLED": {
      return {
        ...state,
        // The old post must be filtered out, the updated post must be added, then the array must be sorted.
        userTripReports: [...state.userTripReports].filter(tripReport => tripReport.id !== action.response.id).concat(action.response).sort((a, b) => a.id < b.id),
        tripReports: [...state.tripReports].filter(tripReport => tripReport.id !== action.response.id).concat(action.response).sort((a, b) => a.id < b.id),
        response: action.response
      }
    }
    case "UPDATE_TRIP_REPORTS_REJECTED": {
      return {
        ...state,
        error: action.error
      }
    }
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

and here is the user reducer:

```
const initialState = {
  fetching: false,
  fetched: false,
  adding: false,
  added: false,
  user: {},
  error: null,
}

/* Reducer Function*/
export default function (state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "FETCH_USER_PENDING": {
      return {
        ...state,
        fetching: true
      }
    }
    case "FETCH_USER_FULFILLED": {
      return {
        ...state,
        fetching: false,
        fetched: true,
        user: action.user
      }
    }
    case "FETCH_USER_REJECTED": {
      return {
        ...state,
        fetching: false,
        fetched: false,
        error: action.error
      }
    }
    case "PUT_USER_DATA_PENDING": {
      return {
        ...state,
        adding: true,
        added: false,
      }
    }
    case "PUT_USER_DATA_FULFILLED": {
      return {
        ...state,
        adding: false,
        added: true,
        user: action.user
      }
    }
    case "PUT_USER_DATA_REJECTED": {
      return {
        ...state,
        adding: false,
        added: false,
        error: action.error
      }
    }
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

Where on the action 'PUT_USER_DATA_FULFILLED' I would like to update the tripReport state to rerender the homepage.

Comment: When you say a "posts store" and a "users store", are you actually calling `createStore()` twice?  Or are you using one store with two separate "slice reducers", like `combineReducers({users : usersReducer, posts: postsReducer})` ?  We recommend using only one store, with multiple slice reducers.

Comment: Sorry my post was unclear; I do only have one store with combined reducers, but since they are divided, it's giving me issues with rerendering .

Comment: Can you show both the reducers and the component's `mapState` function?

Comment: Yes, I added them to the post